# Upgrading from material ui v1.0.0-beta

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We are currently running an app with material-ui version 1.0.0-beta.27 and react version 16.2.0.

Recently we have been having performance issues with components such as the table. All solution we have found online simply say to upgrade to the latest version of material ui.

The problem is there is no clear and documented way to convert from 1.0.0-beta upwards. The biggest problem I see right off the bat is that our current import structure looks like

```
import Table from 'material-ui/table';
```

While the imports for the newer versions all look like

```
import Table from '@material-ui/core/table'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have no idea how to go about updating our project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [migration guide](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0x/#where-should-i-start-in-a-migration-). In particular, you should run their [codemod](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-codemod) which I imagine will fix the imports for you. Just make sure you *commit* before using the tool.